# How to create temporary one-off terraform resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have searched the mailing list and the documentation for how to do this but couldn't find anything.

Here's my use case: I have a fairly simple architecture on AWS. Sometimes I want to test one-off things, such as whether the security group configuration is right.

To do that, I spin up two instances. Because I don't like clicking (and because those instances need to be set up in different parts of the VPC), I have defined those in a terraform `.tf` file.

I would like those two instances to be spun up only when I explicitly require them. In other words, when I do `terraform apply`, I don't want those instances to be created.

Here are a couple things I tried:

- Put them in a `temp` subdirectory, and execute only this file (e.g. with `terraform plan -out=disposable.plan -target=temp/disposable.tf`). Problem: it does not detect any change ("No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.").
- I had tried something else with a subdir (don't remember exactly why), and terraform complained about undefined variables and resources. Problem: I need access to the variables and resources I define in the main directory (e.g. the subnet ids, security groups, etc.)
- I tried also applying the file directly (not sure if that should work) with `terraform apply temp/disposable.tf`. Problem: it complains about the file not being valid with "not a valid plan file" (the file is indeed valid).
- Rename the file to something else, e.g. `.tf.temp`, and rename it to `.tf` when I need the resource. This works fine, but then you have to remember not to commit this change. I would prefer something that can be done on the command line (e.g. running a single `.tf` file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is achievable using count and a [conditional](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#conditionals):

Set up a variable with a default value of `false` in `variables.tf`:

```
variable temp_instances {
  default = false
}
```

Use this when defining your instances by setting the count property with a [conditional](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#conditionals) like this:

```
resource "aws_instances" "temp1" {
  ...
  count = "${var.temp_instances ? 1 : 0}"
  ...
}
```

Since the variable is `false` by default it will set the count to 0 and not create the instance. You can then optionally set it up by setting this variable to true during an `apply`:

```
terraform apply -var 'temp_instances=true'
```

Using the above conditional, this will now be true, therefore setting the count to 1.